# jQuery read XML URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

My below code working well but i need to import XML data from xml URL not from HTML file like this
if i need to retrieve image from XML how i can do that.

```
var xml = "<shows><show><date>9/8</date><place>Toads Place</place><location>New Haven, CT</location><time>9PM</time></show></shows>"

$(document).ready(function(){
    //$('#table').append('<h2>SHOWS</h2>'); 
    $('#table').append('<table id="show_table">'); 
    $(xml).find('show').each(function(){
        var $show = $(this);
        var date = $show.find('date').text();
        var place = $show.find('place').text();
        var location = $show.find('location').text();
        var time = $show.find('time').text();
        var html = '<tr><td class="bold">' + date + '</td><td class="hide">' + place + '</td><td>' + location + '</td><td class="bold">' + time + '</td></tr>';
        $('#show_table').append(html);
    });
    //alert($('#show_table').html());
})
```

all what i need is change this var xml = "9/8 ... " to let the JQuery code read from the ONLINE URL

Answer (score 6):

If you need to load XML data from the URL, you need to execute AJAX request, it may be something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "http://yoursite.com/yourfile.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data) {
            /* handle data here */
            $("#show_table").html(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status) {
            /* handle error here */
            $("#show_table").html(status);
        }
    });
});
```

Keep in mind, if you use AJAX you can place .xml file on the same domain name. In other case you need to set up `cross-origin resource sharing` (CORS).

**EDITED:**

I modified your code, now it appends `td` element to your table. But xml is still inside html.

```
var xml = "<shows><show><date>9/8</date><place>Toads Place</place><location>New Haven, CT</location><time>9PM</time></show></shows>"

$(function() {
    $(xml).find('show').each(function() {
        console.log(this);
        var $show = $(this);
        var date = $show.find('date').text();
        var place = $show.find('place').text();
        var location = $show.find('location').text();
        var time = $show.find('time').text();
        var html = '<tr><td class="bold">' + date + '</td><td class="hide">' + place + '</td><td>' + location + '</td><td class="bold">' + time + '</td></tr>';
        $('#show_table').append($(html));
    });
});
```

But you need to modify your html file, check my solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/a4m73/

**EDITED: full solution with loading xml from URL**

I combined two parts described above, check here: http://jsfiddle.net/a4m73/1/

Comment: its not .xml file its URL ONLINE how i can do this in my code

Comment: please, provide this URL if possible. I don't fully understand your question

Comment: i do this local in .html file but XML URL ONLINE apply this to my code please

Comment: lsn i write the code locally in .html file and i have online xml url so how i can add this code to my code where ?

Comment: exactly like this   w3schools.com/xml/note.xml 
its the same ?? ur URL .php

Comment: just replace url from my example by **your own url**, it does not depends from extension

Comment: your URL is text not XML

Comment: please, post here **your url**, I will fix it and apply to your code :)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml

i need to retrieve description and name in the table

Comment: it's impossible to retrieve .xml via ajax from w3schools.com, because it does not support CORS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: on the server side of your url. please, post your url here! or let's stop to spam in the comments.

Comment: here my code i need to retrieve (Via,message and time) in the table 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [jquery-xpath](https://github.com/ilinsky/jquery-xpath), then you can easily do what you want like:

```
$(xml).xpath("//shows/show");
```

if you want know more about xpath just take a look on [XML Path Language (XPath)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) document.

```
var xml = "<shows><show><date>9/8</date><place>Toads Place</place><location>New Haven, CT</location><time>9PM</time></show></shows>";

$(document).ready(function () {
    //$('#table').append('<h2>SHOWS</h2>'); 
    $('#table').append('<table id="show_table">');
    $(xml).xpath("//shows/show").each(function () {
        var $show = $(this);
        var date = $show.find('date').text();
        var place = $show.find('place').text();
        var location = $show.find('location').text();
        var time = $show.find('time').text();
        var html = '<tr><td class="bold">' + date + '</td><td class="hide">' + place + '</td><td>' + location + '</td><td class="bold">' + time + '</td></tr>';
        $('#show_table').append(html);
    });
})
```

Comment: i need to remove the inline xml like this var xml="<>" and add the URL